# areas routes mapping issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm working with areas controllers as well as simple default controller. I want to make areas controller (Public) as a default route i.e public/home/home but when I go to simple controller i.e account/login it returns wrong url which is public/account/login instead of home/index.

```
endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute
                (
                    name: "default",
                    areaName: "Public",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Home}/{id?}"
                );
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute
                (
                    name: "withOutArea",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"
                );
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute
                (
                    name: "area",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
```

Comment: what's `when I go to simple controller i.e account/login it returns wrong url which is public/account/login instead of home/index.`  mean? When you go to account/login, the url is `account/login`, why it will be `home/index`? You need to describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: How to make a default route by using area. I want to make /Public/Home/Index make as default route.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net core will not show the full route in default route, It will just show defualt route like `https://localhost:xxxxx`. If you want show the full route, you need to use `url Rewrite`. I write a simple demo here:

```
//url rewrite
var rules = new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRedirect(@"^.{0}$", "Service/Home/Privacy");
app.UseRewriter(rules);

//..........

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute
    (
        name: "area",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

    //set the default route 
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute
    (    
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{area=Service}/{controller=Home}/{action=privacy}/{id?}"
    );

});
//......
```

**Then the default url is `https://localhost:xxxxx/Service/Home/Privacy`**

The other method is add `launchUrl` in your `lunchSettings.json`.

Fisrt you need to add `[Route("service/Home/Privacy")]` in privacy action, then add `"launchUrl": "https://localhost:xxxxx/service/home/privacy"` in `lunchSettings.json`.

When you run the project, The defualt url is also `https://localhost:xxxxx/Service/Home/Privacy`